# VTABLE for derived call doesn't override

Tags: c++

Can some one help me how many VTABELS are created for this code. I am confused here.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    virtual void func()
    {
        cout << "base" << endl;
    }

};

class D : public B 
{
public:

};

int main()
{
    B b1, b2;
    D d1, d2;
    d1.func();
    return 0;
}
```

I believe 4 Vptrs will create here for object b1, b2, d1, d2 respectively i s that right or 6 Vptrs?

Comment: vtables are a implementation detail. There are other means to realize polymorphism.

Comment: What does not override? What output do you expect and why?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `vtables` and `vpointers` is specific to the compiler.
Generally speaking you will get

1. One `vtable` per class that has a virtual function.
2. One `vpointer` per object of the class that has `vtable`.

So based on this **generic approach**

- `B b1, b2;` will have 2 vpointers
- `D d1, d2;` will have 4 vpointers( 2 for the d class and 2 for the b)

So in the end you will have 6 vpointers.

Also note for the dynamic polymorphism(override) to work you will need pointers and **not** stack objects, although this is another topic.

Comment: Got it , thanks !! But in this case class D will not have any VTABLE from compiler ? or is it compiler dependent

Comment: That is compiler depended.                                                                                           
Note again that to make the override work you must use pointers                                  ```D* d1 = new D(); d1->func();.```                                                                                      If my answer helped you give it an upvote!